# Setting the cursor position in a NumericUpDown Control

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms

I have created a user control tha inherits from the NumericUpDown Control.
Is it possible to set the cursor position within the control? 
I am validating the text OnKeyUp, and formatting it when it meets certain criteria.
To do this i have to do me.text = Fomatted(Me.Text), which sets the cursor back to the position 0, i want to set it to the end of the text area.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use

```
yourNumericUpDown.Select(desiredPosition,0)
```