# Numericupdown force thousandsseperator to update text each keypress

Tags: c#, numericupdown

When I use a numbericupdown object with thousandsseperator set to true it only updates the text to display the commas correctly when it loses focus.  Is there a way to force it to refresh each time the value is changed?

Comment: This sound like a bad idea to me... Suppose the user wants to get rid of the thousands separator just before entering/deleting/replacing a digit, are you going to put it back in his face?

Comment: What I'd like to handle is something like if the value was 100, and they add a 0 at the end to make it 1000 it should show 1,000 right when the 0 is entered.  I don't want it to wait until focus is lost for the commas to be populated correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to do an event.
As we know, the thounsandseperator is triggered by focus we can simply call it as we type.

```
 private void numericUpDown1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            numericUpDown1.Focus();
            //Edit:
            numericUpDown1.Select(desiredPosition,0)
        }
```

So as the user type, we give the box the it focus back which is a hack to recall the thousandsseperator formatting.

Note: Problems with hacks are wierd situations which calls for more hacks... e.g: Cursor sets back to the front of the text... you would need another hack to fix it.

Experiment with the other events to find the one that fits your case.

Edit: Btw, if you do want to go even further with this ...

1. Keep Track of the cursor.
2. Put back the cursor at the right position when keyup is called.
   [Setting the cursor position in numericUpDown control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2719948/setting-the-cursor-position-in-a-numericupdown-control)

Answer (score 0):

To format the text value in your control you'd need a call to ParseEditText() which is protected but can be accessed from a class which inherits NumericUpDown. The problem is after your call the cursor will move before the first character. In order to control the position of the cursor you need access to the SelectionStart property which NumericUpDown don't expose. NumericUpDown still has a field named upDownEdit of type UpDownEdit. The UpDownEdit class although internal inherits from TextBox and behave much like one. So a solution would be to inherit from NumericUpDown and use reflection to get/set the value of upDownEdit.SelectionStart. Here is something you can work on:

```
public class NumericUpDownExt : NumericUpDown
{
    private static FieldInfo upDownEditField;
    private static PropertyInfo selectionStartProperty;
    private static PropertyInfo selectionLengthProperty;

    static NumericUpDownExt()
    {
        upDownEditField = (typeof(UpDownBase)).GetField("upDownEdit", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        Type upDownEditType = upDownEditField.FieldType;
        selectionStartProperty = upDownEditType.GetProperty("SelectionStart");
        selectionLengthProperty = upDownEditType.GetProperty("SelectionLength");
    }

    public NumericUpDownExt() : base()
    {
    }

    public int SelectionStart
    {
        get
        {
            return Convert.ToInt32(selectionStartProperty.GetValue(upDownEditField.GetValue(this), null));
        }
        set
        {
            if (value >= 0)
            {
                selectionStartProperty.SetValue(upDownEditField.GetValue(this), value, null);
            }
        }
    }

    public int SelectionLength
    {
        get
        {
            return Convert.ToInt32(selectionLengthProperty.GetValue(upDownEditField.GetValue(this), null));
        }
        set
        {
            selectionLengthProperty.SetValue(upDownEditField.GetValue(this), value, null);
        }
    }

    protected override void OnTextChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
        int pos = SelectionStart;
        string textBefore = this.Text;
        ParseEditText();
        string textAfter = this.Text;
        pos += textAfter.Length - textBefore.Length;
        SelectionStart = pos;
        base.OnTextChanged(e);
    }
}
```